# Make a matrix from a data frame containing numeric and character value

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame containing three columns like this:

```
     IS1     IS2     Dist
      A       A       0
      A       B       1
      A       C       2
      A       D       3 
      B       B       0
      B       C       4
      B       D       5
      C       C       0
      C       D       6
      D       D       0
```

I would like to obtain a matrix like this:

```
     A    B    C    D
 A   0    1    2    3  
 B   1    0    4    5  
 C   2    4    0    6
 D   3    5    6    0
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you need `r1 <- xtabs( Dist ~IS2 + IS1, df1); r1+ t(r1)` ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to show us your code. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `xtabs`

```
r1 <- xtabs( Dist ~IS2 + IS1, df1)
r1+ t(r1)
```

Comment: Just the xtabs() function does it. Why do you add r1 + t(r1) ?

Comment: @satnam  If you look at the OP's output, then it needs the mirror image elements also the same